# Is there a way to control Microsoft Teams Application with my application?

Tags: windows, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

Are there any client apis exposed by Teams which i can use to control some basic settings of Teams or is there any other way which i can do it ?

Comment: What sort of functionality you are looking for in your App, We have list of [Graph API Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-concept-overview) available, You should take a look at this, Apart from that if you are looking for something else Let me know

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT I was thinking starting with Camera Toggle and Conference Mute features, and later on move on to other features.

Comment: There is [call mute API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/call-mute?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) available but not video toggle

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT My requirement is dynamic change in Teams application controls on their system (client side) itself for now. Like instead of muting the call in Teams application I want to mute it in my application itself without leaving it. Will graph api you pointed out work like that ? Do you have any links to examples with this on hand ? If so it will be very helpful.

Comment: Currently You cannot mute in your Application. when you use Call Mute API it will mute on Teams Application. This is by design.

Answer (score 1):

There is [call mute API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/call-mute?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) available but not video toggle. You cannot mute in your Application. when you use Call Mute API it will mute on Teams Application. This is by design.